# A logic problem involving conjunctions and disjunctions

Tags: logic

1. $(P \vee Q)$ & $R$
2. $(R$ & $P) \rightarrow S$
3. $(Q$ & $R) \rightarrow S$

Conclusion is $S$

without using conditional proof, please?

And perhaps if you have time, please show me the conditional proof method or at least which CP you would use.
Thank you & I do appreciate your time.

My difficulty is that I've been learning from a book, that does not actually give all the answers to the problems set.
The ones not given are seemingly more difficult than the answered ones.

I did try

4. $Q~~~~~~$    2$~~$ SIMP
5. $P$&$Q~$  1,4 CONJ
6. $R~~~~~~$    1$~~~$ SIMP

I did see/thought I did a Constructive Dilemma CD but was not a 100% certain I could apply it.
Apologies for not showing that I had actually made an effort.
:D

*Critical thinking* 9th Edition by Richard Parker & Brooke Noel Moore, p. 339 Q2.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please take the tour (http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and use MathJax (https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, please say what you tried so far, so it's easier for us to help you.

Comment: @bobh: This problem is from what book, what chapter, what problem number?

Comment: ' Critical thinking ' 9th Edition by Richard parker & Brooke Noel Moore. p339 Q2

Comment: I will probably have another go in the morning.

Comment: @bobh: In your posted attempt, step $4$ is wrong. Simplification allows you to get any of the two parts of a conjunction. But premise $2$ is an implication, not a conjunction. Even if step $4$ was right, step $5$ is wrong since premise $1$ doesn't give you $P$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version is almost the same as my first answer, and it's the same length, but by making use of "Constructive Dilemma", it's perhaps conceptually a little simpler. The proofs are exactly the same for the first $10$ steps.

\begin{align*}
\text{Given:}&&1.&\;\; (P \lor Q) \land R\\[2pt]
&&2.&\;\; (R \land P) \to S\\[2pt]
&&3.&\;\;(Q \land R) \to S\\[12pt]
\text{To prove:}&&S&\\[12pt]
\text{Proof:}&&4.&\;\; P \lor Q&&\text{[$1$, SIM]}\\[2pt]
&&5.&\;\; R&&\text{[$1$, SIM]}\\[12pt]
&&6.&\;\; \lnot (R \land P) \lor S&&\text{[$2$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&7.&\;\; (\lnot R \lor \lnot P) \lor S&&\text{[$6$, DEM]}\\[2pt]
&&8.&\;\; \lnot R \lor (\lnot P \lor S)&&\text{[$7$, ASSOC]}\\[2pt]
&&9.&\;\; R \to (\lnot P \lor S)&&\text{[$8$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&10.&\;\; \lnot P \lor S&&\text{[$9,5$, MP]}\\[2pt]
&&11.&\;\; P \to S&&\text{[$10$, IMP]}\\[12pt]
&&12.&\;\;(R \land Q) \to S&&\text{[$3$, COM]}\\[2pt]
&&13.&\;\; \lnot (R \land Q) \lor S&&\text{[$12$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&14.&\;\; (\lnot R \lor \lnot Q) \lor S&&\text{[$13$, DEM]}\\[2pt]
&&15.&\;\; \lnot R \lor (\lnot Q \lor S)&&\text{[$14$, ASSOC]}\\[2pt]
&&16.&\;\; R \to (\lnot Q \lor S)&&\text{[$15$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&17.&\;\; \lnot Q \lor S&&\text{[$16,5$, MP]}\\[2pt]
&&18.&\;\; Q \to S&&\text{[$17$, IMP]}\\[12pt]
&&19.&\;\; (P \lor Q) \to (S \lor S)&&\text{[$11,18,4$, CD]}\\[2pt]
&&20.&\;\; S \lor S&&\text{[$19,4$, MP]}\\[2pt]
&&21.&\;\; S &&\text{[$20$, TAUT]}\\[2pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you again Quasi, I have printed it out

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you arrived at line 19 ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how you arrived at line 19?  I thought the CD rule applied on 11,18,4 would have just been S V S  giving S ? Why did you put the term (P v Q)➟ (S V S ) ?  I know I have used up a fair bit of your time, but this minor point threw me off a bit.

Comment: The conclusion of "Constructive Dilemma" is an "or" of two propositions, not a single proposition. Of course in this case, the two propositions being "ored" are both $S$, so in one more step, you get $S$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align*}
\text{Given:}&&1.&\;\; (P \lor Q) \land R\\[2pt]
&&2.&\;\; (R \land P) \to S\\[2pt]
&&3.&\;\;(Q \land R) \to S\\[12pt]
\text{To prove:}&&S&\\[12pt]
\text{Proof:}&&4.&\;\; P \lor Q&&\text{[$1$, SIM]}\\[2pt]
&&5.&\;\; R&&\text{[$1$, SIM]}\\[12pt]
&&6.&\;\; \lnot (R \land P) \lor S&&\text{[$2$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&7.&\;\; (\lnot R \lor \lnot P) \lor S&&\text{[$6$, DEM]}\\[2pt]
&&8.&\;\; \lnot R \lor (\lnot P \lor S)&&\text{[$7$, ASSOC]}\\[2pt]
&&9.&\;\; R \to (\lnot P \lor S)&&\text{[$8$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&10.&\;\; \lnot P \lor S&&\text{[$9,5$, MP]}\\[12pt]
&&11.&\;\;(R \land Q) \to S&&\text{[$3$, COM]}\\[2pt]
&&12.&\;\; \lnot (R \land Q) \lor S&&\text{[$11$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&13.&\;\; (\lnot R \lor \lnot Q) \lor S&&\text{[$12$, DEM]}\\[2pt]
&&14.&\;\; \lnot R \lor (\lnot Q \lor S)&&\text{[$13$, ASSOC]}\\[2pt]
&&15.&\;\; R \to (\lnot Q \lor S)&&\text{[$14$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&16.&\;\; \lnot Q \lor S&&\text{[$15,5$, MP]}\\[12pt]
&&17.&\;\; (\lnot P \lor S) \land (\lnot Q \lor S) &&\text{[$10,16$, CONJ]}\\[2pt]
&&18.&\;\; (\lnot P \land \lnot Q) \lor S &&\text{[$17$, DIST]}\\[2pt]
&&19.&\;\; \lnot (P \lor Q) \lor S &&\text{[$18$, DEM]}\\[2pt]
&&20.&\;\; (P \lor Q) \to S &&\text{[$19$, IMP]}\\[2pt]
&&21.&\;\; S &&\text{[$20,4$, MP]}\\[2pt]
\end{align*}

Comment: I have to make more effort and do these every day. So embarrassing, really. thank You very much for your time. Would the solution have been much shorter, using a ' conditional proof ' ?

Comment: I'm not sure -- I haven't thought about it. But I see a way to make it slightly shorter using "Constructive Dilemma". I'll post that as a separate answer.

Comment: Ok thank you. You're brilliant. I knew i should have kept practicing these everyday. I got totally lazy.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure it's any better, and it's actually the same size, not shorter. I'll post it anyway -- it's worth looking at, but I'll delete it after about an hour.

Comment: From following your working out, I notice you deal with each term in order and deconstruct them. I have got the hang of it a bit better now. I think I will be doing some PL every day from now on. Thank you for your help @quasi